# Declare Angular dependencies asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, requirejs

I'm using angular and also lazy-loading the controllers with requirejs, but now I get another doubt how to declare or register angular dependency asynchronously that means I have a angular app which depends on both ng-route and as well as ng-calendar so I have written

```
var app = angular.module('moduleName',['ngRoute','ui.calendar']);
```

but only one controller requires calendar plugin and the controller is serves as asynchronously, to improve performance I want to lazy load the calendar plugin with controller when route changes....

Sorry for my english...

Please help me?

Comment: i havent used this but it may achieve what you are after https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: Thanks @Burrito for suggesting that plugin, i think this plugin solves my problem, but i want to do some examples with that...

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a `define(['angular', ...]` section in your file? You also need to add the javascript file that contains module `ui.calendar` as a dependency.

Comment: hai @orange, I'm doing the way what you have said, but what i want to downoad `ui.calendar`only  when a route change then a specific controller is downloaded and executed asynchronously.

Comment: In that case, you have to download `ui.calendar` using `require(...)`. But then the whole module which uses components from `ui.calendar` needs to be defined in the `require(...)` response callback, as the dependencies for this module are only available at this time. I'm not sure how Angular handles dynamic module creation. I would imagine all modules must exist prior to starting the angular app.